# A question on Linear First-Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I encountered an example from a [book](https://www.sciencedirect.com/handbook/handbook-of-computational-economics/vol/1/suppl/C) that can be summarized as follows:

- Let $\gamma > 0$ be a scalar, $c(x)$ be a function of $x$, $\beta \in [0;1)$, and $\lambda$ be a real parameter.
- On the region $[0;\gamma)$, a function $V(x)$ has the form $$V(x) = -c(x) + \beta\int_{x}^{\infty} V(y)\lambda\exp(-\lambda(y-x))\mathrm{d}y.$$
- On the interval $[\gamma,\infty)$, $V(x)$ is a constant and $V(x) = V(\gamma) = \dfrac{-c(\gamma)}{1 - \beta}.$
- Differentiate $V(x)$ with respect to $x$ on the interval $[0;\gamma)$, we obtain:
  $$V'(x) = -c'(x) + \lambda c(x) + \lambda(1-\beta)V(x).$$
- It said that the equation $V'(x) = -c'(x) + \lambda c(x) + \lambda(1-\beta)V(x)$ is a "linear, first-order differential equation that can be integrated to yield the following closed-form solution for $V(x)$" and the solution is:
  $$V(x) = \frac{-c(\gamma)}{1-\beta} + \int_x^\gamma \frac{c'(y)}{1-\beta}[1-\beta\exp(-\lambda(1-\beta)(y-x))]\mathrm{d}y.$$

My question is, how can we obtain the solution as stated in the book as above? To obtain the linear ODE $V'(x)$, I can work it out using the Leibniz integral rule and by replacing the integral part by $V(x) + c(x)$. However, for the solution of this equation, I'm quite stuck.

Comment: You said you can "work out" $V'(x)$.  So if you substitute that in to the differential equation, are the two sides equal?  If so, $V(x)$ is a solution of the differential equation.

Comment: I mean I can differentiate $V’(x)$ and do some substitutions to obtain the right hand side of $V’(x)$ as above. Maybe my words make some confusion. Anyway, my question is about the step or suggestions to obtain the solution of the differential equation.